# Error en CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

Tengo un ploblema con el FrameWork de CodeIgniter, me marca el siguiente error que se muestra en la captura de pantalla pero no es el codigo porque si cumple la funcionalidad correctamente.
Espero y me puedan ayudar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un error de incompatibilidad de versiones tanto de `mysql` como de `PHP`  para más detalles puede revisar https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247338/6502043

Comment: de descargo otras versiones y te respondo si me funciona

Comment: es por el metodo de autenticación de mysql, reinstalalo y/o configurale el metodo viejo.